# How to byepass a older version jar with new?

Tags: jar, wso2, wso2-esb

I have written a class mediator and used it in wso2 esb which uses ehcache-core-2.6.6 jar so i have put this jar in \esb_home\repository\components\lib folder but here is the twist, I have a jar as ehcache_1.5.0.wso2v3 jar in esb_home\repository\components\plugins. This jar comes with wso2 esb. Now when i run my proxy containing the class mediator, it takes refrence of  ehcache_1.5.0.wso2v3 jar instead of ehcache-core-2.6.6 jar so due to this i am getting error as:

```
[2013-05-14 17:10:59,898] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;)Lnet/sf/ehcache/CacheManager;
        at tempuri.data.cachable.CacheData.cacheData(CacheData.java:32)
        at tempuri.data.cachable.CacheData.mediate(CacheData.java:26)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:223)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:443)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:166)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:217)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

So, my question is how can i byepass the jar ehcache_1.5.0.wso2v3 when running my proxy and refrence the jar ehcache-core-2.6.6 which i need to refrence?Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance

I have followed what ratha has mention in his reply to this question but after doing those steps, i am getting this error and my esb doesn't get started:

```
    JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to D:\eclipse\java\jdk1.7.0
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to D:\BPEL_wip\WSO2ES~1.0\bin\..
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,438] DEBUG - CarbonContextDataHolder Started Setting up Authenticator Configuration
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,498] DEBUG - StAXUtils About to create XMLInputFactory implementation with classloader=org.eclipse.
core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@2413d9
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,498] DEBUG - StAXUtils The classloader for javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory is: null
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,518] DEBUG - StAXDialectDetector StAX implementation at jar:file:/D:/BPEL_wip/wso2esb-4.6.0/lib/end
orsed/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.wso2v2.jar!/ is:
  Title:         null
  Symbolic name: geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec
  Vendor:        woodstox.wso2.org
  Version:       1.0.1.wso2v2
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,528] DEBUG - StAXDialectDetector Detected StAX dialect: Woodstox
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,528] DEBUG - StAXUtils Created XMLInputFactory = class org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.Immutable
XMLInputFactory with classloader=org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@2413d9
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,528] DEBUG - StAXUtils Configuration = DEFAULT
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,528] DEBUG - StAXUtils Size of XMLInputFactory map for this configuration = 1
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,538] DEBUG - StAXUtils Configurations for which factories have been cached = [DEFAULT]
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,578] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,678] DEBUG - MiscellaneousUtil The name with ' secret.manager.conf ' cannot be found. Using default
 value secret-manager.properties
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,678] DEBUG - SecretManager Configuration properties can not be loaded form : secret-manager.propert
ies Will use synapse properties
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,678] DEBUG - SecretManager No global secret provider is configured.
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,678] DEBUG - SecretManager No secret repositories have been configured
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,708] DEBUG - StAXUtils About to create XMLOutputFactory implementation with classloader=org.eclipse
.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@2413d9
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,708] DEBUG - StAXUtils The classloader for javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory is: null
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,708] DEBUG - StAXUtils Created XMLOutputFactory = class org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.Immutabl
eXMLOutputFactory for classloader=org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@2413d9
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,708] DEBUG - StAXUtils Configuration = DEFAULT
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,708] DEBUG - StAXUtils Size of XMLOutFactory map for this configuration = 1
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,708] DEBUG - StAXUtils Configurations for which factories have been cached = [DEFAULT]
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,728] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamWriter is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamWriterWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,748] DEBUG - MTOMXMLStreamWriter Calling MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,748] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,748] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamWriter is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamWriterWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:25,758] DEBUG - MTOMXMLStreamWriter Calling MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,738] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,758] DEBUG - CarbonContextDataHolder Completed Setting up Authenticator Configuration
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,758] DEBUG - CarbonContextDataHolder Unload Tenant Task: org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonCon
textDataHolder$CarbonContextCleanupTask was registered.
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,798] DEBUG - CarbonContextDataHolder Loading Cache Configuration
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,808] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,818] DEBUG - CacheConfiguration Successfully loaded Cache Configuration
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,818] DEBUG - CarbonContextDataHolder Initializing Cache Manager
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,818] DEBUG - EhcacheManager cache manager initialized
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,828] DEBUG - CarbonContextDataHolder Unload Tenant Task: org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonCon
textDataHolder$MultitenantCarbonCacheManager$CacheCleanupTask was registered.
[2013-05-16 12:22:26,828] DEBUG - CarbonContextDataHolder there can be a possibility of the same class loading twice and
 then trying to reset the initial context factory builder
java.lang.RuntimeException: A queue manager instance has already been set.
        at org.wso2.carbon.queuing.CarbonQueueManager.setInstance(CarbonQueueManager.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder.<clinit>(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:231)
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getThreadLocalCarbonContext(CarbonContext.java:94)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout$TenantAwarePatternParser.<init>(TenantAwarePatternLayo
ut.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout.createPatternParser(TenantAwarePatternLayout.java:81)
        at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:435)
        at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:427)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout.<init>(TenantAwarePatternLayout.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:120)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:641)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:612)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:509)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:441)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:468)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
        at com.atomikos.logging.Slf4jLogger.<init>(Slf4jLogger.java:8)
        at com.atomikos.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactoryDelegate.createLogger(Slf4JLoggerFactoryDelegate.java:7)
        at com.atomikos.logging.LoggerFactory.createLogger(LoggerFactory.java:12)
        at com.atomikos.logging.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:52)
        at com.atomikos.transactions.internal.AtomikosActivator.<clinit>(AtomikosActivator.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,088] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,238] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,258] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamWriter is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamWriterWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,268] DEBUG - MTOMXMLStreamWriter Calling MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,378]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,378]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Windows 7 6.1, x86
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,378]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : D:\eclipse\java\jdk1.7.0\jre
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,388]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.7.0
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,388]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 21.0-b17,Oracle Corp
oration
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,398]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : D:\BPEL_wip\WSO2ES~1.0\bin\..
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,398]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : D:\BPEL_wip\WSO2ES~1.0\bin\..\tmp
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,398]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : 313123, en-US, Asia/Calcutta
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,608]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter RAM size (MB): 2047 of the system is below the recommended min
imum size :2048
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,638]  INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
[2013-05-16 12:22:29,788]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,380] DEBUG - StAXUtils XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWr
apper
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,820]  WARN - ConfigurationFactory No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe
.xml  found in the classpath: bundleresource://39.fwk15181810:1/ehcache-failsafe.xml
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,830] DEBUG - ConfigurationFactory Configuring ehcache from URL: bundleresource://39.fwk15181810:1/e
hcache-failsafe.xml
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,830] DEBUG - ConfigurationFactory Configuring ehcache from InputStream
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,850] DEBUG - BeanHandler Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,850] DEBUG - BeanHandler Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,860] DEBUG - DiskStoreConfiguration Disk Store Path: D:\BPEL_wip\WSO2ES~1.0\bin\..\tmp
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,870] DEBUG - CacheManager Creating new CacheManager with default config
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,940] DEBUG - PropertyUtil propertiesString is null.
[2013-05-16 12:22:34,950] DEBUG - ConfigurationHelper No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
[2013-05-16 12:22:35,010] DEBUG - Cache No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
[2013-05-16 12:22:35,010] DEBUG - Cache CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
[2013-05-16 12:22:35,020] DEBUG - ConfigurationHelper No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
[2013-05-16 12:22:35,030] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getJCache(Ljava/lang/String;)Lnet/sf/ehcache/jcache/JCache;
        at org.wso2.carbon.caching.core.ehcache.EhcacheManager.getCache(EhcacheManager.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$MultitenantCarbonCacheManager.getCache(CarbonContext
DataHolder.java:719)
        at org.wso2.carbon.caching.core.BaseCache.<init>(BaseCache.java:34)
        at org.wso2.carbon.caching.core.realm.RealmCache.<init>(RealmCache.java:29)
        at org.wso2.carbon.caching.core.realm.RealmCache.getInstance(RealmCache.java:39)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:116)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2013-05-16 12:22:35,420] DEBUG - JspRuntimeContext Parent class loader is: WebappClassLoader
  context: /
  delegate: false
  repositories:
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@1a39812

[2013-05-16 12:22:35,430] DEBUG - JspRuntimeContext Compilation classpath initialized: D:\BPEL_wip\wso2esb-4.6.0\lib\tom
cat\work\Catalina\localhost\_;null
[2013-05-16 12:22:35,440] DEBUG - JspServlet Scratch dir for the JSP engine is: D:\BPEL_wip\wso2esb-4.6.0\lib\tomcat\wor
k\Catalina\localhost\_
[2013-05-16 12:22:35,450] DEBUG - JspServlet IMPORTANT: Do not modify the generated servlets
[2013-05-16 12:22:37,060] DEBUG - UpdateChecker Update check failed:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:483)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:213)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:316)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:992)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:928)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:846)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
        at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.getUpdateProperties(UpdateChecker.java:108)
        at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.doCheck(UpdateChecker.java:72)
        at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(UpdateChecker.java:60)
        at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.run(UpdateChecker.java:51)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 2 versions at same time..Remove the one in plugin folder and edit the bundle.info file to remove that particular line.
and keep your newer version jar in the lib folder as you tried.

Comment: so i should remove ehcache_1.5.0.wso2v3 jar from plugins folder? If i remove this jar from plugin it throws error.And where i will find the bundle.info file?

Comment: After removing older jar from plugin folder, remove the particular entry(a line contains particular ehcahe .jar detail) from buindle.info (home\4.6.0\repository\components\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundle.info) and save it. keep the new version jar in the lib folder and restart the server

Comment: i did exactly the same but got error while starting ESB as:[2013-05-15 10:07:44,262] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Error occured while deployi
ng bundles in the dropins directory
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid line in the bundles.info file:
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.util.BundleInfoLine.getInstance(BundleInfoLine.java:87)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.processBundlesInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:144
)

Comment: without ehcache_1.5.0.wso2v3 jar esb is not getting started. I have removed the jar from plugins folder as well as i have removed the refrence of this jar from bundle.info but i am getting the above error:(

Comment: if you properly removed the line from bundle.info its fine. But you need to keep the newer version in the lib folder, then required classes will be avilable in the classpath

Comment: i have completely removed the line mentioning ehcache_1.5.0.wso2v3 jar from bundle.info and has put the new version of jar in lib folder but it gives the above error. Somewhere else it is being refrenced, i guess so

Comment: Is there no solution to this problem?

Comment: clean the dropins folder first, and keep the newer version of the jars in lib and restart the server. This should work!

Comment: No it hasn't worked for me:(.I am still getting the same error. Why i don't know:(